# How to serialize JAXB object to JSON with JAXB reference implementation?

Tags: json, jaxb

The project I'm working on uses the [JAXB reference implementation](https://jaxb.java.net/), i.e. classes are from the `com.sun.xml.bind.v2.*` packages.

I have a class `User`:

```
package com.example;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name = "user")
public class User {
    private String email;
    private String password;

    public User() {
    }

    public User(String email, String password) {
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

}
```

I want to use a JAXB marshaller to get a JSON representation of a `User` object:

```
@Test
public void serializeObjectToJson() throws JsonProcessingException, JAXBException {
    User user = new User("user@example.com", "mySecret");
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(User.class);

    Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();

    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    marshaller.marshal(user, sw);

    assertEquals( "{\"email\":\"user@example.com\", \"password\":\"mySecret\"}", sw.toString() );
}
```

The marshalled data is in XML format, not JSON format.
How can I instruct the *JAXB reference implementation* to output JSON?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

JAXB reference implementation does not support JSON, you need to add a package like [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) or [Moxy](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/#moxy)

### Moxy

```
 //import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextProperties;
 
 Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>(2);
 properties.put(JAXBContextProperties.MEDIA_TYPE, "application/json");
 properties.put(JAXBContextProperties.JSON_INCLUDE_ROOT, false);
 JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(new Class[] {User.class}, properties);

 Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
 marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
 marshaller.marshal(user, System.out);
```

See example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158056/jaxb-mapping-to-json)

### Jackson

```
//import org.codehaus.jackson.map.AnnotationIntrospector;
//import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;
//import org.codehaus.jackson.xc.JaxbAnnotationIntrospector;

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();  
AnnotationIntrospector introspector = new JaxbAnnotationIntrospector(mapper.getTypeFactory());
mapper.setAnnotationIntrospector(introspector);
     
String result = mapper.writeValueAsString(user);
```

See example [here](http://tshikatshikaaa.blogspot.com/2012/08/jaxb-json-marshalling-unmarshalling.html)